# Sliding menu in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need a sliding menu like this :

[image: sliding menu]

Please help me to create it.
Or introduce a library or component to create it

I'm new in C# and I don't know any thing about WPF.

Comment: the `Expander` control should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Expander` control will do exactly what you need, you may just have to style the `ToggleButton` to match your concept, but otherwise it seems to fit your requirement

Example:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <Expander Header="Expander 1" >
        <Border Height="100" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Expander 2">
        <Border Height="100" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Expander 3">
        <Border Height="100" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
    </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sa_ddam213! I cant vote up but your answer but it is very useful